# jQuery - Compatibility Problem with Internet Explorer 7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have this code that dynamically slides up a Div over an image when mouse over it. It works perfectly in Firefox and Google Chrome, but in Internet Explorer 7 everything runs really slow and nothing happen.

The jquery code is this:

```
jQuery.fn.masque = function(class) {

$(this).hover(function(){
$(this).find(class).stop().animate({height:'100px',opacity: '0.9'},400);
},function () { 
$(this).find(class).stop().animate({height:'0',opacity: '0'}, 300);
});
}
$(document).ready(function(){$('.thumb').masque('.masque');});
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="thumb bg25">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/image.jpg" alt="Something" /></a>
        <div class="masque">
            <h3 class="someclass"><a href="#" >Some text here</a></h3>
            <p class="someclass">Some text here</p>
            <p class="someclass">Some text here</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.thumb {float:left; margin:0 14px 14px 0; width:126px; height:186px; padding:10px; position:relative;}

.masque{position:absolute; background:#212326; width:118px; bottom:10px; height:0; padding:4px; display:none;}
```

I;m running it from a local machine, not in  a server.

.. so I think I'm doing something wrong and maybe there is an efficient way for achieving this effect.
Thanks!!!

Comment: In case you need here is the CSS:

.thumb {float:left; margin:0 14px 14px 0; width:126px; height:186px; padding:10px; position:relative;}

.masque {position:absolute; background:#212326; width:118px; bottom:10px; height:0; padding:4px; display:none;}

Comment: @Jonathan - it would be better to edit your question and add the CSS in a code block :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried taking the stop() off?  I'm totally shooting in the dark, but I'm thinking that IE7, might be queing the calls differently.  I'll test it now.

### Update

After testing it I'm getting some wierd errors in IE7 because of the variable named class.  That must be some sort of keyword.  Try this.

```
jQuery.fn.masque = function(classSelector) {
        $(this).hover(function(){
                $(this).find(classSelector).stop().animate({height:'100px',opacity: '0.9'},400);
        },function () {
            $(this).find(classSelector).stop().animate({height:'0',opacity: '0'}, 300);
        });
};
```

### Update

have your tried using slideUp and slideDown?

```
jQuery.fn.masque = function(classSelector) {
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $(this).find(classSelector).slideDown();
    },function () {
        $(this).find(classSelector).slideUp();
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks! In case you need here is the CSS:

.thumb {float:left; margin:0 14px 14px 0; width:126px; height:186px; padding:10px; position:relative;}

.masque {position:absolute; background:#212326; width:118px; bottom:10px; height:0; padding:4px; display:none;}

Comment: BTW, in the future instead of adding the css to the comment add it to your post but note that addition in a comment.

Comment: Thanks, now I see the div sliding up in IE7 but its still really slow, not well positioned and buggy... Maybe there is a better way for coding it?

Comment: BTW this is a code I copied from www.foliostars.net and I modified it... so I dont really understand jQuery...

Comment: Whats the size of your image.

Comment: Using slideUp and slideDown gives me the same buggy behavior in IE... Maybe I need to test it in a server and not in my local machine...

Comment: @bendewey - you can collaborate with OP by using http://jsbin.com It works really well for demo'ing code